# Unity equivalent for Ninject's Bind.ToMethod of IPrincipal,IIdentity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, ninject, iidentity

I'm trying to replicate the following Ninject syntax in Unity, but not having any luck:

```
Bind<IIdentity>().ToMethod(c => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);
```

I'm thinking it ought to look something like:

```
IUnityContainer container;
...
container.RegisterType<IIdentity>(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);
```

How should it be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While [neontapir's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8246867/15861) answer could work, that extension method is Obsolete. The correct way to do this now would be to use an [InjectionFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.injectionfactory%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx):

```
container.RegisterType<IIdentity>(new InjectionFactory(u => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
container.RegisterInstance<IIdentity>(...);
```

Comment: This wouldn't work as it would capture the current instance of User.Identity, and always return that. The OP wants the User.Identity to be **evaluated** every time the container is asked to resolve an IIdentity.

Comment: True. If the exact semantics is required then your answer is obviously closer to this.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity isn't available when the container is initialized, so yes wanted it to be evaluated each time.

Comment: The key is you want: () => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity NOT HttpContext.Current.User.Identity

Answer (score 0):

I believe a [static factory extension](http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/RegisteringFactoryMethodCreateObjectsUnityStaticFactoryExtension.aspx) would do it. I'm rusty on Unity. Seeman's *Dependency Injection in .NET* is a good resource for situations like this.